# How to embed html form in Microsoft Bot Framework - nodejs

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want, Bot to send html form[with some fields and submit button] to user, where user can fill out the form and submit.
Once user submits the form, form action routes to dialog where i can retrieve the user data.

Is this possible in Microsoft Bot framework - **Node.Js**?? If so, How to achieve this ?
Please any Help.....

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing channels (i.e. Facebook, Slack, etc.) support posting of HTML forms as of yet.  If you are building your own channel via Direct Line you can roll your own.   Take a look at [FormFlow](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html) on the C# client or Waterfalls in the node client for text-based input flow.